# Correct pattern for recursive api call in react redux-thunk

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-thunk

We want to make a recursive API call based on the number of records received in the response.
For example, if the number of records we get is 10 and the total records are 20, we need to call to the same API again with an updated marker (i.e., we are making calls to next 10 records).

So, what should be the correct pattern to call the API again? Should I do a `.then()` to the first dispatch(it is inside componentDidMount method) or should I call the API again instead of dispatching the first response.

Though the first option works but it would cause the render method to be called multiple times and I am not sure if that is the correct pattern or not.

```
componentDidMount() {
    store.dispatch(getCustomerData('1234',1,10)).then((res) => {
     //do some login and call store.dispatch(getCustomerData('1234',2,10)) again
   })
  }
```

Comment: Hello, when do you want to call the second api, do you want to call it in the componentDidMount or do you want something similar to infinite scrolling.

Comment: We have a table to be shown with all the records and we cannot do server pagination due some restrictions. The api responds back with max of 1000 records so, if we have a scenario that total records are more than 1000 we need to make another call and want to load the table only after getting all the records. @octobus

Comment: How will you understand if there are more than 1000 records? Is it when you get the response from the api or do you know it before you call the api?

Comment: Yes there is a total record field in the response. We'll check it with that.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so based on on your comments I would suggest to just call one function in your componentDidMount and call your api inside this function. After getting response you can check if there is more data and call your api again for the other datas. Like you said using `.then()` will do the work. 
I hope I explained myself clearly, if not please say it so I can describe it with more detail.

Comment: Okay, i'll try it further and will wait for further discussion.

Comment: Also if you fear that this method will cause multiple renders, it won't be. Because you should dispatch you data to your reducer after calling you last api. So your reducer will be change only once and it won't re-render multiple times.